# How to use eventsource (server sent events) in Next.js Serverless functions deployed on Vercel?

Tags: node.js, next.js, vercel, server-sent-events

How can I make the below example work using `serverless functions` that is deployed on Vercel? I can't use `edge functions` as some of the dependencies (Firebase) require `node.js` and I couldn't find any resource on how to use `eventsource` in `next.js` `serverless functions` or whether it's possible at all.

source: https://github.com/Nutlope/twitterbio/blob/main/pages/api/generate.ts

/api/generate:

```js
import { OpenAIStream, OpenAIStreamPayload } from "../../utils/OpenAIStream";

if (!process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY) {
  throw new Error("Missing env var from OpenAI");
}

export const config = {
  runtime: "edge",
};

const handler = async (req: Request): Promise<Response> => {
  const { prompt } = (await req.json()) as {
    prompt?: string;
  };

  if (!prompt) {
    return new Response("No prompt in the request", { status: 400 });
  }

  const payload: OpenAIStreamPayload = {
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages: [{ role: "user", content: prompt }],
    temperature: 0.7,
    top_p: 1,
    frequency_penalty: 0,
    presence_penalty: 0,
    max_tokens: 200,
    stream: true,
    n: 1,
  };

  const stream = await OpenAIStream(payload);
  return new Response(stream);
};

export default handler;
```

OpenAIStream.ts:

```js
import {
  createParser,
  ParsedEvent,
  ReconnectInterval,
} from "eventsource-parser";

export type ChatGPTAgent = "user" | "system";

export interface ChatGPTMessage {
  role: ChatGPTAgent;
  content: string;
}

export interface OpenAIStreamPayload {
  model: string;
  messages: ChatGPTMessage[];
  temperature: number;
  top_p: number;
  frequency_penalty: number;
  presence_penalty: number;
  max_tokens: number;
  stream: boolean;
  n: number;
}

export async function OpenAIStream(payload: OpenAIStreamPayload) {
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();
  const decoder = new TextDecoder();

  let counter = 0;

  const res = await fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY ?? ""}`,
    },
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
  });

  const stream = new ReadableStream({
    async start(controller) {
      // callback
      function onParse(event: ParsedEvent | ReconnectInterval) {
        if (event.type === "event") {
          const data = event.data;
          // https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create#completions/create-stream
          if (data === "[DONE]") {
            controller.close();
            return;
          }
          try {
            const json = JSON.parse(data);
            const text = json.choices[0].delta?.content || "";
            if (counter < 2 && (text.match(/\n/) || []).length) {
              // this is a prefix character (i.e., "\n\n"), do nothing
              return;
            }
            const queue = encoder.encode(text);
            controller.enqueue(queue);
            counter++;
          } catch (e) {
            // maybe parse error
            controller.error(e);
          }
        }
      }

      // stream response (SSE) from OpenAI may be fragmented into multiple chunks
      // this ensures we properly read chunks and invoke an event for each SSE event stream
      const parser = createParser(onParse);
      // https://web.dev/streams/#asynchronous-iteration
      for await (const chunk of res.body as any) {
        parser.feed(decoder.decode(chunk));
      }
    },
  });

  return stream;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal `res.write()` and `res.end()` with serverless function.

Steps:

- Read OpenAI response as a stream and parse it with `eventsource-parser` package to extract the content.
- In `onParse` callback you can stream the response to the client using `res.write()` and end the response when `data: [DONE]` as [OpenAI mention in their docs](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create#chat/create-stream).

I applied this method in my project as an alternative way to use edge functions.
[cover-letter-generator](https://github.com/MohamedAlosaili/cover-letter-generator).
You can find more details and code in the repo

- `src/utils/fetchOpenAIAPI.ts` for fetching OpenAI API.
- `src/utils/OpenAIStreamForServerless.ts` to stream the response to the client.

I hope this helps.